# No puedo mostrar el nombre de un usuario logueado con aws authentication

Tags: angular, aws, cognito

Resulta que estoy trabajando en un login con Angular y AWS authentication y cognito, luego de loguearse se redirige a un Home con un navbar,. Mi problema es que quiero capturar el nombre de usuario logueado y mostrarlo en el navbar. Lo intenté hacer capturando el nombre de usuario en una variable y  mostrandolo en mi template de navbar, pero al momento de recargar la página desaparece el nombre del usuario y me muestra 'Undefined', aquí les dejo mi código :

Este es mi servicio donde capturo el usuario al hacer un logueo exitoso

```
  signIn(username, password) {
    Auth.signIn(username, password).then(data => {
      if (data) {
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        this.cognitoUser = data.username;
        console.log(data);
      }
    })
  }
```

Este es el controlador del navbar es donde lo capturo en una variable para luego mostrarlo:

```
constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,
          private router: Router,
          private logs: LoginService) {
  user = this.logs.cognitoUser;
}
```

Este es mi template donde intento mostrar la variable en  navbar:

```
<mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="light">
        <button type="button" mat-button (click)="drawer.toggle()">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
        <span class="col text-right">{{user}}</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: Cuando pones *Aquí hago...* no indicas si ese código es un controlador, un servicio... es complicado hacerse a la idea de dónde está el fallo.

Comment: Macho, estoy investigando como hacer esto, ¿¿¿ de dónde has sacado la información???

Comment: Disculpa xd soy novato, ya puse que codigo es cada uno, espero logres entender xd.

Comment: Y la informacion la eh sacado de la misma documentacion de AWS authentication, eso en cuanto al servicio de loggueo.

Comment: He creado una sala, la encontrarás en el footer de esta misma página, en la parte izquierda donde pone "chat"

Comment: si entra pero el problema es que no me deja escribir xd

Comment: Pos nada, yo encontré este código en el git, quizás te sirva: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cognito-angular-quickstart  No encuentro en la doc aws el login con Angular, ¿me pasas el link?

Comment: Gracias, le echare un vistazo, mira aquí la documentación: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/angular y este es el Authentication: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication

Comment: cognitoUser es una propiedad de tu servicio? de ser así los datos se van a perder cuando refrescas ya que vuelve a su estado inicial, lo mas conveniente sería guardar en localStorage el userName

Comment: Gracias amigo, lo resolví de la manera en la que sugeriste.